# Is it possible to provoke a semicolon after declarations to avoid -Wextra-semi?

Tags: c, macros

I'm writing a C program with a macro that defines a function. Unfortunately, doing this throws off my formatter. But when I add an extra semicolon, I get a warning. Is there a way to define a macro to be invoked outside a function body that requires or allows a semicolon after it w/o warning so that the result looks like syntactically valid C to the formatter?

The specific macro is:

```c
#define define_foreach(name, type)\ 
     inline void foreach_##name(void (*f)(type), type* array, size_t len) {\ 
         for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)\ 
             (*f)(array[i]);\ 
     }
```

Comment: You can put `typedef char NeverUseThis` at the end. It is a declaration that can be repeated without error and that needs to be terminated with a semicolon. Still, playing games with macros to satisfy your formatter is generally a bad idea. The formatter should be adjusted, not the code.

Comment: @schuelermine, Please post usage examples.

Comment: Commonly you can add certain comments to the source to calm your formatter. Which one are you using?

Comment: I’m using `clang-format`